# Upper bound on real roots of depressed cubic

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics, upper-lower-bounds

Given a depressed cubic equation
$$x^3+px+q=0,$$
with $p$ and $q$ negative real numbers, is there an easy upper bound for its real roots in terms of $p$ and $q$? The sharper the better, of course.

**EDIT:** I had little clue how to approach this problem. I tried substituting polynomials of low degree in $p$ and $q$ for $x$, such as $x=p+q$ and $x=\sqrt{-p}$ to see whether the result would be positive or negative in general, but to little avail. I don't see how to approach this constructively, or how to find simple expressions to plug in that will always yield a positive result.

Comment: There is exact values which are kind of both upper and lower bounds at the same time? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: If $q, p$ are positive then an easy bound is $q/p$

Comment: @vrugtehagel From what I recall these expressions are somewhat unwieldy involving many choices of signs, and it is not immediately clear which choices of signs yield the largest value. Do please correct me if I am overlooking something obvious.

Comment: @MathUser_NotPrime Coincidentally the examples I am looking at have $p$ and $q$ both negative.

Answer (score 1):

There is a general bound $M$ on the moduli of the (real or complex) roots $\,\xi_i\,$ in $\mathbf C$ of a polynomial of any degree  $n$ in $\mathbf C[x]$, $ a_n x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_1x+a_0\enspace (a_n\ne 0)$:
$$|\xi_i|\le M=\max\biggl(1, \frac{|a_{n-1}|}{|a_n|}+\dots+\frac{|a_{0}|}{|a_n|}\biggr). $$
For a depressed cubic, this yields the bound $\; M=\max(1,|p|+|q|)$.

On the other hand, [Sturm's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem) yields the exact number of distinct real roots in a given interval.